# Jquery - Event on enter key press only the first time in a TextBox

Tags: jquery

I have a TextBox and I make a AJAX request when the user presses the Enter key.

```
$('#TextBox1').on('keypress', function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
               // ajax request
            }  
        });
```

How can I make it that this event fires only the first time the user presses the enter key?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4xbUv/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.</strike>

```
$('#TextBox1').one('keypress', function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
               // ajax request
            }  
        });
```

`.one()` is like `.on()` but it's only executed once.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4xbUv/1/)**

Try:

```
var foo = false;
$('#TextBox1').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 &! foo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("pressed");
        foo = true;
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4xbUv/3/)**

Comment: the function is not firing at all?! no alert when i press enter

Comment: You have to click in the textbox first.

Comment: Yes, but if I write text first, and then press 'Enter', the alert won't fire because the first time it was executed the key was not enter...

Comment: What's not what you asked for in your question.

Comment: The question was "Event on *enter* key press only the first time in a TextBox" not "keyup only once"... thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and solved through below code....
and its working fine. I hope this code will also help you.

```
var EnterKeyPressed = false;

   $('#TextBox1').keypress(
    function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && EnterKeyPressed == false) {
            EnterKeyPressed = true;
            return true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && EnterKeyPressed == true) {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score -2):

I had fallen in kinda similar problem. The below code works for me btw.

```
var executed = false;
$(document).on("keydown", function () {
  if (executed === false) {
    executeForOnce();
    executed = true;
  }
});
```